How to use alternative make for parallelizing dvisvgm in make4ht on windows
On linux, make4ht is able to parallelize the build of SVGs in dvisvgm. It looks like  dvisvgm_hashes.lua expects to run exactly "make -j". I'm stuck with jom (https://wiki.qt.io/Jom) for parallel builds on windows. Is there a way to override the use of make with another build tool?
Also, I manually ran "jom my-latex-file-images.mk" from the command line with the Makefile generated for "make" and it built the SVGs. However, the emitted files don't have the hash extension to the filename, so I think I'm missing something else.
Thanks,
Allen

With the updated make4ht sources, in particular with the updated dvisvgm_hashes extension, you can use the following build file:
filter_settings "dvisvgm_hashes" {
  scale= 1.6,
  make_command = "jom -j ${process_count} -f ${make_file}",
  test_make_command = "jom -v" -- or any other command that will produce some output
}

The two new settings are make_command and test_make_command. I don't have any possibility to test if it works, but assuming that it is a replacement for make, it should.

Can I drop that version of dvisvgm_hashes.lua into my TeXLive 2019 installation or do I need more of the make4ht code?

@Allen dvisvgm_hashes is quite old extension, so it is likely that it will work even with TeX Live 2019. But it is in general a good idea to update such old distro.

Thanks again! I had to comment out the logging calls for it to work with the old installation. But it correctly invokes jom.

I have another issue: the script is not renaming the svg files. At line 204, I added some print statements:
    print( file )
    print( page )
    print( make_hashed_name(arg.input, dvi_pages[page]) )
    local a,b = os.rename(file, make_hashed_name(arg.input, dvi_pages[page]))
    print(a)
    print(b)
  end```
An example output is:
```user_manual-010.svg
10
user_manual-6eb9e42ae42fd8873f938cae7c49353b.svg
nil
Invalid argument```

@Allen more interesting debugging message would be print(make_hashed_name(arg.input, dvi_pages[page])), what does that print?

Sorry. I didn't do a very good job formatting my response.
print(make_hashed_name(arg.input, dvi_pages[page])
printed
user_manual-6eb9e42ae42fd8873f938cae7c49353b.svg

@Allen you can update your question with formatted code and the command line output to make it more readable. But It seems that the source SVG and hashed SVG file names are fine, it is just os.rename that has an issue.

Yes. The hashed name looks OK to me, too. I was able to rename a couple of files with the move command and through the file manager; so, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly wrong with the name. I don't know how to debug that. Can I test os.rename with  a lua script that is invoked directly without going through LaTeX?

@Allen it seems that os.rename can have problems with certain filenames on Windows, but I don't see anything wrong with the names generated by make_hashed_name. Try if this works: ```local f = io.open("xxx.txt", "w")
f:write("hello")
f:close()
os.rename("xxx.txt", "aaa.txt")


You can execute it using the texlua command.

Your script worked correctly under texlua. I'll install TeX Live 2024 and see if that helps.

@Allen I hope the update will help!

Aha! The issue is that on windows dvisvgm's log file has CRLF line endings. So, the log file parser in dvisvgm_hashes:get_generated_pages leaves the CR in the file variable. If I trim that off, it works as expected.

@Allen ah, thanks for catching that! I've updated sources of the extension to ignore CR characters. I hope it will fix this.
